# lambda function not printing values instead printing object value

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, output

I have a script that emails me links to me.

The problem is the links arent included, instead I get:

```
<function <lambda> at 0x7f75b5fb4a60>
```

**My script looks like:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests

ex_webdev_js_by_city = [
'http://boston.website.org/search/web',
]

ex_web_j_keywords = [['one'],['coool', 'person']]
ex_web_j_keywords = sum(ex_web_j_keywords, [])

ex_js = []

for webdev_j_for_a_city in ex_webdev_js_by_city:
    webdev_j = requests.get(webdev_j_for_a_city)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webdev_j.text, "lxml")
    for j_keyword in ex_web_j_keywords:
        for a in soup.find_all('a', class_="result-title hdrlnk", text=re.compile(j_keyword,re.IGNORECASE)):
            #print(a.get('href'))
            ex_js.append(a.get('href'))

if ex_js:
   #email them to myself!
   import smtplib, socket
   TO = 'myemail@gmail.com'

   try:
       server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
       server.starttls()
       TEXT = lambda: print(('Latest js from site:\n\n{}'*len(ex_js)).format(*ex_js))
       #Gmail Sign In
       gmail_sender = 'myemail'
       gmail_passwd = 'mypass'
       server.login(gmail_sender, gmail_passwd)
       msg = str(TEXT)
       server.sendmail(gmail_sender, gmail_sender, msg)
       print('Sent you some links!')
       server.quit()
   except socket.error as e:
       print ('error sending mail, error was {}'.format(e))
```

The error is occuring on this line (I believe):

```
lambda: print(('Latest js from site:\n\n{}'*len(ex_js)).format(*ex_js))
```

It appears its printing out the `object details` in the email to me, and not the `value`.

Thus, what am i possibly doing wrong here?

Comment: First of all, the value is `None` since you "return" a `print` statement and secondly, why do you use lambda?

Comment: The `lambda` function isn't doing anything because it is never called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you use `print` or `lambda` anyway. If you simply wrote:

```
msg = ('Latest js from site:\n\n{}'*len(ex_js)).format(*ex_js)
```

and drop the:

```
msg = str(TEXT)
```

it should probably work.

So the `try` block should read:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
msg = ('Latest js from site:\n\n{}'*len(ex_js)).format(*ex_js)
#Gmail Sign In
gmail_sender = 'myemail'
gmail_passwd = 'mypass'
server.login(gmail_sender, gmail_passwd)
# msg = str(TEXT) !!commented out!! (only to make it explicit)
server.sendmail(gmail_sender, gmail_sender, msg)
print('Sent you some links!')
server.quit()
```

---

I think however that you do not really understand what `lambda` and `print` are supposed to do. `print` is used **to write data to the standard output channel**, but you want to write it into an email, so you do not need to print it locally, you need somehow to store your message **in memory**.

Finally `lambda:...` is used to create an **anonymous function**, if you do not feed it any arguments, its usage is usually to postpone execution (for instance to achieve laziness). But here you actually **need the message**, so again no need to use this construct.

Comment: I think you mean to comment out `msg=str(TEXT)` ?

Comment: @Jshee: comment out or remove. Indeed, my bad... Sorry.

Comment: This is really helpful. So, to use `format()` i dont need to call a function like `print()` before?

Comment: @Jshee: no format is a function defined on a string (as you can see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.format#str.format)), `print` has nothing to do with that. When you use it, you only **feed the output of `.format` to `print`**.

Answer (score 1):

When you say

```
TEXT = lambda: print(('Latest js from site:\n\n{}'*len(ex_js)).format(*ex_js))
```

Yo are simply creating lambda function , it is not executed yet . In order to execute you need to specifically invoke it by calling `TEXT()`

In order to fix your problem change to

```
TEXT = lambda: ('Latest js from site:\n\n{}'*len(ex_js)).format(*ex_js)
```

And `msg = str(TEXT())`

Comment: You don't use `return` in `lambda` functions; the result of the expression is returned implicitly. And yeah, a `lambda` isn't needed at all in this case anyway.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I was trying to answer the original question. Not trying to questioning his code. And you are  absolutely correct, this scenario we don't need lambda